# Search one text file for values in another text file

Tags: vb.net

i want to search a text file for values contained in another text file. the result displays the values not contained in list 2

```
Public Class Form1

    Const TEST1 = "\\folder\compare\list1.txt"
    Const TEST2 = "\\folder\compare\list2.txt"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
          ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Declare two dictionaries. The key for each will be 
    ' the text from the input line up to,
    'but not including the first ",". 
    ' The valus for each will be the entire input line.

    Dim file1 As New HashSet(Of String) '!
    'Dim file1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim file2 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST1)
        Dim part() As String = line.Split(",")
        If Not file1.ContainsKey(part(0)) Then file1.Add(part(0), line)

    Next

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST2)
        Dim part() As String = line.Split(",")
        If Not file2.ContainsKey(part(0)) Then file2.Add(part(0), line) '!
    Next

    AddText("The following lines from " & TEST2 & " are also in " & TEST1)

    For Each key As String In file2.Keys
        If file1.Contains(key) Then
            AddText(file2(key))
        End If
    Next
    Dim keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2 = file1.Except(file2.Keys).ToList '!



    Dim values = From key In keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2 Select file1(key)
    Dim str = String.Join(vbCrLf, values)
    AddText("ID should not be in this list" & str)

    End Sub

    Private Sub AddText(ByVal text As String)
        txtResults.Text &= text & vbCrLf
    End Sub

End Class
```

i want to search a text file for values contained in another text file. the result displays the values not contained in list 2. at the moment it works so long as the values are unique. I want to search a large text file for specific values.

Comment: Well Dictionary has the method ContainsKey() which you can use to determine if a key exists as part of the dictionary. If true, adding the same key again will cause the error.

Comment: if the values are no longer unique, then use `.ContainsKey` when reading the files and dont add items which already exist.  this assumes that non unique keys are not associated with unique values.

Comment: thanks guys, can you insert where i would put ,containskey, im not familiar with how to use it. Ie copy and paste code to an answer with contains key.

Comment: looks like it's already been used in the code you provided: file1.ContainsKey(key)

Comment: ok i removed file1.Add(part(0), line)  but now nothing gets passed to file1 and 2 for the for loop and contains key method?

Comment: can someone please help no answers are being posted only comments

Comment: i have changed it to dictionary but  it still wont build, my file conatins all charecter types. have you any idea why im getting a Conversion from string "-" to type 'Integer' is not valid. and where i may need to do a conversion and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution seems to be looking only for the first occurence so it is necessary to ignore duplicities when creating file1, file2

```
Public Class Form1

    Const TEST1 = "\\folder\compare\list1.txt"
    Const TEST2 = "\\folder\compare\list2.txt"

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _ 
              ByVal e As System.EventArgs)       Handles Button1.Click
    'Declare two dictionaries. The key for each will be 
    ' the text from the input line up to,
    'but not including the first ",". 
    ' The valus for each will be the entire input line.

    Dim file1 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)
    Dim file2 As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST1)
        Dim part() As String = line.Split(",") 
        If Not file1.ContainsKey(part(0)) Then  file1.Add(part(0), line)'!

    Next

    For Each line As String In System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(TEST2)
        Dim part() As String = line.Split(",") 
        If Not file2.ContainsKey(part(0)) Then  file2.Add(part(0), line)'!

    Next

    AddText("The following lines from " & TEST2 & " are also in " & TEST1)

    For Each key As String In file2.Keys
        If file1.ContainsKey(key) Then
            AddText(file2(key))
        End If
    Next
    Dim keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2 = file1.Keys.Except(file2.Keys).ToList

    Dim values = From key In keysInList1ThatAreNotInList2 Select file1(key)
    Dim str = String.Join(vbCrLf, values)
    AddText(str)

End Sub

Private Sub AddText(ByVal text As String)
     txtResults.Text &= text & vbCrLf
End Sub
```

**Note** To avoid confusion I have deleted the original answer. This is new complete one.

Comment: thanks ivan that seems to work, the only problem is i need to narrow down the search to only look for items with the word ID followed by a number so the search would be something like IF line = ("ID%"&value) condition do you know what the best way to do a search on a combined string like this. I assumed you would use a wildcard like %.

Comment: You need something as `If line like "ID*" & value Then` ([Like Operator (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/vstudio/swf8kaxw(v=vs.110).aspx)) for more complex matching is better to use [Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).